# How do I actually get the data row using sqlalchemy 2.0 syntax?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm on SQLAlchemy 2.0.19. I am using the SQLAlchemy 2.0 Declaractive table with mapped_column() to map my MSSQL table to the class.  However I'm having trouble actually retrieving the data. Everything I try seems to just get me the object and not the data itself?  I've even found posts here that show the syntax below returning data but for some reason when I try I just get the object. The sqlalchemy docs also don't seem to be correct or maybe it's the wrong version?. What's the correct sytax if I wanted to retreive just 1 or all of the rows? Thanks!

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint, Integer, String, Boolean, DateTime, Date, DECIMAL, CHAR, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class BookingStatus(Base):  
    __tablename__ = "BookingStatus"
    Id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Description = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

with Session_LinxDB() as session:
  result = session.scalars(select(BookingStatus)).first()
  print(result) # I get <app_v1.models.linxdb_models.BookingStatus object at 0x00000221C7B4D190>
  print(type(result)) # I get <class 'app_v1.models.linxdb_models.BookingStatus'>
  
  result = session.execute(select(BookingStatus)).first()
  print(result) # I get (<app_v1.models.linxdb_models.BookingStatus object at 0x00000113C5913FD0>,)
  print(type(result)) # I get <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
```

Comment: The data is in the object, so for the `.scalars` version try `print(result.Id, result.Description)`